# Cast API 'ready' message never getting posted on localhost

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-cast

I'm trying to develop a Google Cast sender application in Chrome.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/chrome_sender) states that

> The API sets the variable cast.isAvailable to true and posts a MessageEvent to the host page’s window object of the form:
>
> `{source: "CastApi", event: "Hello", api_version: [, ]}`

The message part is not happening when I am using my development environment and `localhost`, despite the fact that the api is definitely being injected and run (I can see using chrome developer tools, and also sanity checking `window.cast.isAvailable` in the console returns `true`.)

The code that sends the message is the very last line of the file:

```
"undefined" != typeof chrome && "undefined" != typeof chrome.runtime || window.postMessage({source:cast.NAME, event:"Hello", api_version:cast.VERSION}, "*");
```

The message never gets posted, because on my development machine, `chrome.runtime` is an object.

On my server, the message gets posted because `chrome.runtime` is undefined.

Can someone tell me what `chrome.runtime` is, and why it's set when I access my local development server but not my production one?

How can I debug my sender app on localhost?

Comment: Do you have any other Chrome Extensions (installed on your development environment) that inject content scripts into the samne page ?

Comment: I don't believe so... is there an easy way to check? I think some of the extensions I have work on every page - but I'd expect those to inject it on my server hosted page as well.

Comment: Not all extenions run on every page. You can find out like so: 1. Open the console in developer tools 2. At the bottom there is a dropdown with `<page context>` as the selected value 3. Click on this dropdown and find out what extensions have content scripts injected into this page. Take a look into it and compare if the list of extensions injected is the same for both dev and prod environments

Comment: Thanks - the list of extensions is the same for both environments though.

Comment: Could you post your manifest and the 2 URL (dev and prod) where you access your web-page ?

Comment: How would I get to the manifest? I'm not using a custom extension - just the Google Chromecast one from the store. The URLs are `localhost/sender.html` and `my.server.ip/sender.html`. Both `localhost` and `my.server.ip` are in the whitelisted domains under the cast extension developer options...

Comment: I don't know - it is indeed weird. I would try to disable all extension (except the Goggle Cast) and try again, just to rule out the possibility any other extension affects Google Cast's behaviour. Taking a quick look into the source code, it seems that `api_content_script.js` uses some obsolete chrome APIs whereas `api_script.js` looks more up-to-date, but this stll does not explain the difference between dev and prod (unless there is some "external intervention").

Comment: So running in incognito, and allowing only the cast extension, this still doesn't fire.

Comment: So, when cast is the only enabled extension, it doesn't fire in dev but does fire in prod ?

Comment: Yep, though I've just had a friend over and it works locally when he runs the server on his machine (i.e. what I'm trying to do), but not when he accesses the server running on my machine through his browser. Something weird going on here :(

Comment: So, it must be your server then ;) Are you absolutely sure that the same page is served by all servers ?

Comment: Yep, the code is hosted in a git repo and there are no environment variable based modifications in the server-side code. I just realised my friend may not have whitelisted my ip when we did the test yesterday - I'll check when he's back

Comment: whitelisted my ip and it works on his pc from my local dev server. back to it being an issue with my browser/environment.

Comment: I would try the following: 1. Disable all extentions (including cast). 2. Load the page from your dev server. 3. Open the console and check whether `chrome` and `chrome.runtime` are defined.

Comment: `chrome.runtime` is an object even with all extensions disabled when I access localhost, but thankfully I found a workaround... will post as an answer. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get this to work on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

But as a workaround, I edited my `hosts` file and mapped my machine name to `localhost` and it works when I access via using that alias.

It seems there's something on my operating system or in the version of chrome that I'm running that populates `chrome.runtime` for `localhost`...